# How to return an Int from a c function to Swift code

Tags: c, xcode, swift, output, return-value

I'm having an issue returning an Int from my c code to my swift code.

Im trying to do this in my swift code:

```
// Connect
if(connectToHost(address, port) < 0)
{
    println("Error connecting!")
    exit(1);
}
```

c Function looks like this:

```
int connectToHost(const char *address, int port){
    // irrelevant stuff here
    return connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
}
```

The error I'm getting: "Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments"
Of course because I'm getting an CInt from my c code

I can't seem to find a solition to this issue :/

Comment: How about `if (Int(connectToHost(address, port)) < 0)`?

Comment: Which xCode version do you use? Your code is valid for beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if(Int(connectToHost(address, port)) < 0)
{
    println("Error connecting!")
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explaination to your intension.